# What is the standard practice for designing REST API if it is being used for inserting / updating a list of records

Tags: rest, api, api-design, design-guidelines

We are building an API which will be used for inserting and updating the records in a database. So if the record exists based on the Key the record will be updated and if it does not then it will be inserted.

I have two questions.

- As per REST guidelines, what are the options for designing such an API e.g. PUT / POST OR PATCH? How should the list of objects be represented?
  NOTE: I know from other answers that I read that there is confusion over how it should be as per REST guidelines. So I am OK if I can get some guidance on general best practice (irrespective of REST part)
- Secondly, the part where I am really confused about is how to represent the output of this or what this API should return.

Specific guidance/inputs on above topic would be really appreciated.

Comment: In regards to your 2nd question, in a REST architecture clients should send an `Accept` header informing the server what media type the client supports and the server should pick the one that is the most suitable one for the resource. `application/json` is in general a bad media-type for REST as it doesn't hint the client on any available links nor what type the content actually has.It is just to easy to fall into the [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) trap and preassume a resource having a type, which is wrong from a REST standpoint

Comment: ... though if you are not that much interested in a REST architecture but just the vague thing most developers understand as REST (the buzzword), it is up to you how you fromat the response. You might check if there are certain media types available that already depict the content's meaning. I.e. invoices can be represented in many forms, XML-based, EDIFACT, ZUGFeRD/PDF, ...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many different implementations for inserts/updates across various vendors (Stripe, HubSpot, PayPal, Google, Microsoft). Even though they differ, the difference somehow fits well with their overall API implementation and is not usually a cause for stress.

---

With that said, the "general" rule for **inserts** is:

`POST /customers` - provide the customer details within the `body`.

This will create a new customer, returns the unique ID and customer details in the response (along with `createdDate` and other auto-generated attributes).

Pretty much most, if not all API vendors, implement this logic for inserts.

---

**Updates**, are quite different. Your options include:

**POST**

`POST /customer/<customer_id>` - include attributes and values you want to update within the body.

Here you use a `POST` to update the customer. It's not a very common implementation, but I've seen it in several places.

**PUT**

`PUT/customer/<customer_id>` - include either all, or partially updated attributes within the body.

Given `PUT` is technically an idempotent method, you can either stay true to the REST convention and expect your users to provide all the attributes to update the resource, or make it simpler by only accepting the attributes they want to update. The second option is not very "RESTful", but is easier to handle from a users perspective (and reduces the size of the payload).

**PATCH**

`PATCH /customer/<customer_id>` - include the operation and attributes that you want to update / remove/ replace / etc within the body. More about how to [PATCH](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/).

The `PATCH` method is used for partial updates, and it's how you're "meant" to invoke partial updates. It's a little harder to use from a consumers perspective.

Now, this is where the bias kicks-in. I personally prefer to use `POST`, where I am not required to provide all the attributes to invoke an update (just the ones I want to update). Reason is due to simplicity of usage.

In terms of the response body for the updates, usually they will return object within the response body include the updated attributes (and updated auto-generated attributes, such `updatedDate`).

---

**Bulk inserts/ updates**

Looking at the [Facebook Graph HTTP API (Batch Request)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) for inspiration, and assuming `POST` is your preferred method for updates, you could embed an array of requests using a dedicated `batch` resource as an option.

**Endpoint**: `POST /batch/customers`

**Body**:

```
{
   ["first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"...], //CREATE
   ["id": "777", "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe"...], //UPDATE
   ["id": "999", "first_name": "Mike", "last_name": "Smith"...], //UPDATE
   [....]
}
```

**Sample Response**

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "result":[
      { // Creation successful
        "code": 200,
        "headers":{..},
        "body": {..},
        "uri": "/customers/345"
      },
      { // Update successful
        "code": 200,
        "headers":{..},
        "body": {..},
        "uri": "/customers/777",
      },
      { // A failed update request
        "code": 404,
        "headers":{..},
        "body": {..}, // body includes error details
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: By [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) `PUT` should replace the whole content only. There is a note in that section that clarifies how a partial update can be achieved (`PATCH` or update a resource that partially overlaps an other resource, to the other resource this has an effect of a partial update), but it should NOT be used to send only partial data to the server!

Comment: Further [PATCH](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) is also not an operation where you can send only the attributes that are of interest to you. You might want to [read up](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) on how to patch correctly. With that beeing said, there is actually a [JSON Merge Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396) format that comes probably close to what you suggest though this has to be negotiated between client and server (in a REST architecture) first otherwise the server might not understand what the client requests

Comment: Hi @RomanVottner, I agree that `PATCH` is the correct way to partially update a resource using REST principals. I merely stated the options that are currently available and how existing APIs are enabling updates today. If the choice is to follow REST strictly, then `PATCH` it is. Thank you for sharing the links. Actually what I wanted to describe above is that it should also include the operation in the PATCH, rather than include it in the body as POST/PUT - will update the answer.

Comment: I understand the discussion but the question is specifically with respect to how does this work in case of a list of objects

Comment: @Jags sorry, I missed the point! I've updated the response to include a proposition for bulk objects creation /updates.